# Detect endianness of PostgreSQL cluster

Tags: postgresql, endianness

Some background.
I am working on a show case for indexes. In order to provide more insights into how Postgres handles them, I am using [`pageinspect` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pageinspect.html). My setup (on `9.3.5`) is the following:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pageinspect;
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS pin;
CREATE SCHEMA pin;
SET search_path TO pin,public;

CREATE TABLE bat AS
SELECT id,
       translate((random()*123456789)::text,'0987654321.','abcdefghijk') str
  FROM generate_series(1, 10) id;
ALTER TABLE bat ADD CONSTRAINT p_bat PRIMARY KEY (id);
CREATE INDEX i_bat_str ON bat(str);
VACUUM ANALYZE bat;
```

And now I can show some details (meta and the only leaf page):

```sql
SELECT * FROM bt_metap('i_bat_str');
WITH pages AS (
    SELECT relname, relpages, blkno 
      FROM pg_class ic, generate_series(1,relpages-1) s(blkno)
     WHERE oid='pin.i_bat_str'::regclass
)
SELECT blkno,s.*
  FROM pages, bt_page_items('pin.i_bat_str',blkno) s
 WHERE blkno=1;
```

Last query produces a series of `data` values. I do understand, that [first byte is a single-byte header](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html), and in my case it's least-order bit is set, 'cos I'm on a `x86_64`.

So my question is — is it possible to check server endianness via function (or via SQL) that will not require compiling extra code? I know how to do it in C, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Good question. Not that I know of - though you could use PL/Perl, PL/Python, etc, to do it. If you submit a patch adding such a function we'd probably accept it as a system information function though.

Comment: @vyegorov, Regarding *["Working hard to make my Telecom company (where I work, not that I own it) start using PostgreSQL instead of ORACLE for non-critical systems"](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1154462/vyegorov)*, why are you such a die-hard fan of pgsql?

Comment: @Pacerier, because I haven't seen a better RDBMS yet.

Comment: @vyegorov, [WebScaleSQL](http://webscalesql.org/).

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use plperl or plpython.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION little_endian() RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plperlu AS $$
use Config;
return $Config{byteorder} eq '1234' || $Config{byteorder} eq '12345678';
$$;
```

or:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION little_endian() RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plpythonu AS $$
import sys
return sys.byteorder == "little"
$$;
```